# How to use a vector of pointers to a structure in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, struct, structure

I have an assignment that is due about a week from now. It is about making a letter counter (cases don't matter) of text file in the directory the source file is. Then the output of the letters should be, first, according to the letter with highest number of occurrences of it, and, second, if there are letters with the same number of occurrences, then sorting will be according to the alphabetical order. The assignment page is here: http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/135/tjd/a1.html. I already did a program that has the same output (here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxuBN4fpoq5LNHIwR2U2elVkdVE/view?usp=sharing). The thing is, as what you can see from the assignment page, is that my proffisor is insisting that we use a vector, Freq_table, that has pointers to a structure, char_count. I tried to do simple code to add elements to the vector, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct char_count {
    char c;
    int count;
};

typedef vector<char_count*> Freq_table;

int main () {
    char_count A_count = {'A', 0};
    Freq_table.push_back (A_count);
}
```

But the compiler always gives this message:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token                                      
 Freq_table.push_back (A_count);
```

I can't seem to solve this error. All I need for now is to know what is the syntax of adding elements to a vector that has pointers to a structure.

Regards.

Comment: First figure out how to instantiate a vector.

Comment: You should complain to your department head that your instructor is completely incompetent at C++ programming.  That assignment is reasonable for "we're learning about operators new and delete and why smart pointers were invented, since getting it right by hand is tricky".  For "we're brushing up on C++ by solving a simple problem" that is absolutely **horrible**.  So bad, that professional C++ programmers would not consider it to have solved any problem at all, only created 200 new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is wrong, you are doing something like

```
int.push_back(A_count);
```

Furthermore, you tell your vector that you want to store a pointer to a `char_count`-variable, but you store the variable itself, therefore resulting in another error.
Before you can push values into a vector, you have to declare it. A possible (untested) solution would be

```
Freq_table newTable;
newTable.push_back(&A_count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `Freq_table` as a type, not an instance, so change:

```
typedef vector<char_count*> Freq_table;
```

to:

```
vector<char_count*> Freq_table;
```

To add to the table, you have to pass the address of a char_count instance.  One way is:

```
char_count* A_count = new char_count; // allocate a new instance...returns the address.
A_count->c = 'A';
A_count->count = 0;
Freq_table.push_back(A_count);
```

Don't forget you will have to delete the instances in the vector if allocated with `new` or you will have memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

The only redeeming part of that assignment is that you aren't actually required to use dynamic memory.  You can use the vector of pointers for only the one purpose it is reasonably well-suited, namely for getting the letters sorted by descending frequency.

The pointers in the vector will be **non-owning** pointers.  It is appropriate to use a raw pointer for non-owning pointers, since that can't cause a memory leak.

Something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    char_count dictionary_order[26];
    for( int i = 0; i < 26; ++i ) dictionary_order[i] = {'A'+i, 0};

    /* read the input, count letters.
       Notice that the matching letter is always at index ch-'A' */


    Freq_table frequency_order;
    for (auto& item : dictionary_order) frequency_order.push_back(&item);

    sort(frequency_count.begin(),
         frequency_count.end(),
         [](char_count* a, char_count* b) -> bool
         {
             return (a->count == b->count)? (a->c < b->c) : (a->count > b->count);
         }
        );

    /* print them out */
}
```

No dynamic allocation, therefore no leaks.  And because C++ destroys local variables in the opposite order of declaration, the pointed-to objects will exist longer than the pointers themselves do.

If you needed to accommodate a variable number of items, you could have a `vector<char_count>` that manages the memory, and store pointers to those in your mandated vector of pointers.  Of course, pointers become invalid if the vector is resized, so you'd build the entire "real" vector before starting to fill the pointer vector.